# How to draw a visualization of disjoined set structure for the following p[] array?

Tags: java, disjoint-sets

I have answered the following assignment:

> **Problem 1.** Draw a visualization of the disjoint-set structure as we did in class for the following `p[]` array.
>
> ```
>   i = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],
> p[i]= [2 2 2 3 4 4 4 7 3 7]
> ```
>
> **Problem 2.** Suppose `link(i, j)` is the method as discussed in class that implements lazy linking with
> height (depth) control (i.e., point small into large). Draw a visualization after `link(1,9)` is called on the disjoint-sets data structure with the `p[]` array above. If you have heard of path compression, note that it does this without path compression.

Here are my answers:

[image]

Is my diagram correct?

Comment: Is my diagram correct? I don't know

Comment: Yes, acording to the problem, and I tried something on myself, I'm not sure if the things I tries are right

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the first picture. The first tree should not have 0 as root, but 2. As `p[0]` indicates what the *parent* is of 0, we should see that 2 is a parent node and has 0 as child. The same goes for `p[1]`, and so the first tree should be:

```
      2
     / \
    0   1
```

Also the second picture seems wrong.

First of all, the assignment says that no path compression should be used. That means that nodes 7 and 9 should not become siblings, but should remain in their original parent-child relationship.

Secondly, when two nodes are linked, a disjoint set algorithm will first retrieve the root nodes of the sets (trees) those two nodes are in.

In your example of `link(1, 9)`, the first step would be to find the root of 1, which is 2 as can be seen in the above (corrected) representation. The root for 9 is 7. So now the problem is translated to `link(2, 7)`.

As the assignment states that we should use a *height* controlled join, there is some ambiguity, because both involved trees (the one rooted by 2, and the other rooted by 7) have the *same* height. So we could choose which of these two roots will become the root of the joined set. Maybe in your class a specific algorithm was presented that would break that tie (of equal heights) by giving the first root precedence over the second. If so, then 7 should become the direct child of 2:

```
       2
      /|\
     0 1 7
         | 
         9
```

But there is no reason (nothing in your post) that would prevent us from choosing node 7 as the root, and then it would be:

```
       7
      / \
     9   2
        / \
       0   1
```

But either way, the already existing parent-child relationships should remain as they are when it is given that we should not perform any path compression.